# Magento 2.2 extend.css style sheet changes are not showing on site despite clearing cache

Tags: css, magento, magento2.2

I am working on a magento 2.2 site that has been developed by another company. I need to make some minor alterations to the site's stylesheets but I can't seem to make them appear on site. I have only worked in previous versions of magento before and I remember it being much easier than this!

I have updated the stylesheet that is in the \app\design\frontend..\web\css\ directory (extend.css) and refreshed the site cache, flushed js/css cache, flushed magento cache and cache storage and nothing works.

I have tried creating _extend.less in the same directory (as instructed on another forum) and nothing...

I have also tried directly editing the stylesheet that the browser inspector tells me the styles are being generated from (in directory /var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend/..etc) and cleared all the same cache again. Nothing is working!

Can anyone advise how to make this work?

The site's URL if it is needed is https://stockgone.com

Answer (score 0):

It should be work. To check your css code is really updated or not browse direct url where you added [you mentioned already added direct css code]. For example  pub/static/version1545823281/frontend/vendor/theme/en_US/css/style.css

Refresh well and search your css that you added. If your code is updated then refresh page again hope you will see changes.

I hope you already clean and flush cache by SSH command
php bin/magento cache:clean and php bin/magento cache:flush

You can also browse site with incognito mode from chrome or private mode from firefox. Sometimes browser cache may cause this kind of issue.